# Where should I read lazy column item offset?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Basically I have a launched effect reading the item offset of a lazy column. and based on the offset I change the height/alpha etc..

AS is warning me that it should not be read inside a compose function because it will change a lot, so my question is where should I be reading and what is the best practice here?
Should I make a lambda updating the offset outside of the function and read in the highest one? Or the parent one?

Open to suggestions

[image: AS Warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it inside a `derivedStateOf`.

```
  val someData = remember {
      derivedStateOf { 
          val offset = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
          val firstVisibleItem = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex
          // Convert to some data here and read this data
      }
  }
```

I did similar thing in this [library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-AnimatedList) for animating color, scale and alpha of items with

```
val animationData by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val animationData = getAnimationProgress(
            lazyListState = lazyListState,
            initialFirstVisibleIndex = initialFirstVisibleIndex,
            indexOfSelector = indexOfSelector,
            itemScaleRange = itemScaleRange,
            showPartialItem = showPartialItem,
            globalIndex = globalIndex,
            selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
            availableSpace = availableSpace,
            itemSize = itemSizePx,
            spaceBetweenItems = spaceBetweenItems,
            visibleItemCount = visibleItemCount,
            totalItemCount = totalItemCount,
            inactiveScale = inactiveItemScale,
            inactiveColor = inactiveColor,
            activeColor = activeColor
        )

        selectedIndex = animationData.globalItemIndex
        animationData
    }
}
```

If you read a change you can read LaunchedEffect with snapshotFlow either but as i checked same `lazyListState` is returned so it's not possible to read any change but you can read `lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` or any changing value as alternative to derivedStateOf.

For instance

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
    snapshotFlow { lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset }
        .onEach { 
            // Here we get the change in offset of first visible item
            
            // You might read another value here and do calculation
            lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex
        }.launchIn(this)
}
```

I think reading lazyListState wouldn't pose any problems either. I use this when i only read one value like `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset`, or layoutInfo inside `snapshotFlow`

Comment: If I'm not wrong, remember is to not trigger that logic when something gets recomposed and derviedStateOf is to only update 'someData' when is different to the current somedata value right?

Comment: Btw thanks, this is more than helpful and makes absolute sense!

Comment: Other question, is it really efficient to create a new object every time? Like AnimationData()? Isn't better to modify the properties of a current object?

Comment: This is a very small data class with @Immutable and `val` params. It doesn't have any significant effect but even if you get a new one for each visible item on each scroll position. Touch gestures return `PointerInputChange` object with  `Offset` position for instance. You can modify existing data like selectedIndex, it's a mutable state i also update while calculating this data.   But you need to value of animation data for it to be updated. If it's not read selectedIndex is not updated either.

Comment: In View classes it was advised against creating new object in `onDraw` but in Compose many classes create immutable data classes even for one frame changes. New Size objects, Rect objects and so on. Good thing about Compose is, it recomposes based on scopes not entire screen so even with new objects it's really performant.

Comment: I also need to use this method for passing each item their own scale and color values. If you check the link it will make more sense. Each item should have their data.

Comment: Makes absolute sense! Thanks a lot :D